# How to move science equations from latex (using equalx for ubuntu) to Libre office presentation?

Tags: libreoffice, latex

I am trying to move equations which i created in equalx equation editor for ubuntu to Libre office presentation.
I tried to copy paste the equation code in insert-object-Formula but the size of equation is very small. It can't be readable. Also one can't increase its size.
The only way I know is the following:

1. save it as tex file
2. run it using latex to create dvi and then PDF
3. Then using GIMP-Tools-Rectangular selection
4. Paste the selection in presentation.

I looking for an alternative.

Comment: Possibly related to [How to insert LaTeX formulas in LibreOffice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150503/how-to-insert-latex-formulas-in-libreoffice) on the TeX StackExchange (but I don't know if it works for presentations as well)